# Making a gradient and change colors based on that gradient in Unity3D - C# Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, gradient

I'd like to be able to create a color gradient bar using C# script too look like this: [image]

Then I'd like to say if my number is in range (0.8 - 1.0) make my object that shade of red that's shown in the gradient.

I'm not sure how to approach this. For now I just have 2 solid colors. I have:

```
myGameObject.GameComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
```

for positive values and blue for negative values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Unity's `Gradient` class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gradient.html).  You can create a list of `GradientColorKey[]` and `GradientAlphaKey` - and set each color/time value.  For your purpose, I would use:

```
    Gradient g = new Gradient();
    GradientColorKey[] gck = new GradientColorKey[2];
    GradientAlphaKey[] gak = new GradientAlphaKey[2];
    gck[0].color = Color.red;
    gck[0].time = 1.0F;
    gck[1].color = Color.blue;
    gck[1].time = -1.0F;
    gak[0].alpha = 0.0F;
    gak[0].time = 1.0F;
    gak[1].alpha = 0.0F;
    gak[1].time = -1.0F;
    g.SetKeys(gck, gak);
    myGameObject.GameComponent<Renderer>().material.color = g.Evaluate(1);
```

This will get you the `Color` that corresponds to the number in `g.Evaluate()` so you should change the time parameter in `g.Evaluate(1)` to a variable or whatever you want.  If you're getting transparent or black textures, try changing the `alpha` values in `gak`.  Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: what is alpha? and can my time be any number? (between -6000 to 6000 for example?)

Comment: Also it doesn't seem like it's going through the gradient. just seems so flicker between colors. unless my changes are not significant enough to see

Comment: @2222 Alpha is the "transparency" of the texture.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure exactly what the relative alpha should be.  Perhaps try setting `gck[1].time` to 0 instead of negative 1, and also set `gak[0]` to 1.0F?    The `Gradient` is made to iterate through colors, so it should be able to do what you want, though I haven't much experience with it myself.

Comment: thanks anyway. i mean I saw this code on here as well https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gradient.html
but I'll try different things to see if it's gonna work. I mean i feel like it should work.:/

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry that my example was unsuccessful, but I feel like we must just have some wrong value somewhere.  Ugh... Unity's documentation can be pure gold, or it can be useless.

Comment: Hey it is quite a late reply but I figured out what was wrong with the code. The parameter "time" is actually percentage in float from 0-1 (0-100%). Anything bigger than 1 is clamped at 1 and anything less than 0 is clamped at 0. 

So for this solution red should be at 1 and blue at 0. 

The evaluate call also uses the same percentage with a float from 0-1. So anything bigger or smaller will result in 1 or 0.